# I render react state as an accessible element. How to force the screen reader to focus/reread the element once a button that changes the state is hit?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, accessibility

Imagine I have this very simple React component:

```
const Home = () => {
    const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

    return (
        <>
            <p accessibilityLabel={counter}>{{ counter }}</p>
            <div onClick={() => setCounter(1)}></div>
        <>
    )
}
```

Once the component is mounted, `counter` will be equal to 0 so the screen reader will read out 0 once it focuses on the `<p>` element, but then if the user moves the screen reader's focus to the button and clicks it, `counter` will become 1.

My question is can I somehow make it so that the screen reader rereads the `<p>` element every time `counter` changes?

Comment: What about using an aria live region? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Live_Regions

Comment: indeed a "live region" is the way to go for this. PS there is no such attribute as `accessibilityLabel`. I guess it's meant to be `aria-label`, but that isn't something that's supposed to change in response to user interactions.

Answer (score 0):

If `accessibilityLabel` maps to `aria-label`, this code won't work. `aria-label` [is ignored](https://html5accessibility.com/stuff/2020/11/07/not-so-short-note-on-aria-label-usage-big-table-edition/) and should not be used on most non-operable element types (including `<p>`).

And your div is not a true semantic button until it has `role=button`, and won't be keyboard focusable without `tabindex=0`, so assistive tech wont handle that properly either. It also needs an accessible name, which can be a text node inside, or an `aria-label`.

And that's lots of extra work for the sake of using `<div>` rather than `<button>`. Why not just use `<button>`? Then you get the keyboard handling, focusability and correct semantics 'for free'.

The state change can certainly be handled by making your `<p>` a live region, or better still, `<output>` which is a live region by default.

Comment: I didn’t know about, the `<output>` element, interesting. I quickly checked the react native docs, it doesn’t seem to exist in react native. The only `liveRegion` like equivalent seems to be `accessibilityLiveRegion="polite"` which only works for Android. For the ARIA roles that implement a live region, [the only react native `accessibilityRole` seems to be `alert`](https://reactnative.dev/docs/accessibility#accessibilityrole).